# RestAPI.exchange to return JSON

Tags: spring, spring-rest, spring-restdocs

In our application we are making below call and receive the response as String. Later we manipulate the string into JSON and convert the JSON into HashMap. (we received very huge piece of JSON response and Converting String to JSON and JSON to HashMap. This action takes much time in the application)

ResponseEntity response = RestAPI.exchange(restTemplate, url,
                HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);

Is there any way to get the JSON format response from the RestAPI.exchange or any idea to avoid such time taking action?

Comment: What's the `huge` size of json?

Comment: It would be around 3-4MB. Number of lines in the JSON response is above 60,000. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3-4 MB size is not that much huge, unless you keep the data always in-memory. I assume you process the data, and store it in DB after receiving it from REST.

It's better to get JSON data and convert it into objects, instead of getting objects binary data.

With all the powerful hardware and memory available nowadays, converting 60,000 lines of JSON to objects should not be an issue at all. So you are on right path.